# Java files are not showing errors

Tags: eclipse, ant

[image: My Project Workspace]

I have imported an ANT project like in the image from SVN. But when I edit the Java files it is not showing errors. What are the settings I need to change?

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085938/eclipse-is-not-showing-compilation-errors-in-project-explorer

Comment: A project like the one in the image, or the one in the image? Is the SRC folder set as a Source Folder on the project's Java Build Path property page?

Comment: @nitind U r right. I added. It solved.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the src folder to the project build path issue got resolved.