# Eclipse and Tomcat stopped halting on errors

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Eclipse and Tomcat has stopped stopping/halting on errors in source code. Eclipse does not mark errors, and Tomcat does not halt/stop.

```
    out = response.getWriter();
    db = new ValgDatabasehandler(rb, out);
```

If I change to

```
    out = response.getWriter();
    db = new ValgDatabasehandler(rb, out1);
```

neither Ecplise nor Tomcat stops or marks this in code.

The error appeared yesterday, but I am not sure what or where I have made something wrong in the Eclipse IDE...

EDIT: I started a new project just to see, and there is no such errors in the new one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if automatic building is on in Eclipse.

Comment: It is on. IT sees to be compiling.

Answer (score 1):

what happens if you try to compile it using javac command, if it does not fail then it would mean you have `out1` variable declared already somewhere.

Comment: Hi bhaskar. If I leave out1 in the code it does not compile with javac. This must be some weird setting in Eclipse I have touched? This is not a big codebase, it's a small sourcecode running a simple servlet. Codebase is 300 lines or so.

Comment: Please see if this link helps: - [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085938/eclipse-is-not-showing-compilation-errors-in-project-explorer#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20eclipse%20project,issue%20and%20resolved%20like%20this.&text=Check%20your%20class%20package%2C%20it,will%20not%20show%20compilation%20errors.

Answer (score 0):

This link had the solutiion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23422371/2924347 - I had to edit .classpath as it says in the links solution.

Thanks bhaskar!