# Eclipse does't shows errors in Package Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse stoped showing errors in project explorer window. Currently in I ask Eclipse run class I got message:

```
Error in Workspace

Errors exist in required project(s)

Prog

Proceed with lounch?
```

And I have no possibility to check where are these errors are. How to fix this problem?

Comment: try to clean the project and rebuild it.

Comment: also check if Lint is reporting errors...

Comment: Have you looked in the Problems View if they are visible there?

Comment: Is `Build Automatically` checked? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751495/why-do-errors-no-longer-appear-in-eclipses-package-explorer

Comment: @greg-449's hint solved the problem for me, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Open the Problems view. It will display all the compile time errors & warning in your open Applications. To open that view follow the steps:

```
Go to Window: Show View: Other: General: Problems.
```

Also to view the errors in Project Explorer, try cleaning the project, as suggested by Vimal Bera.